# How can I make my Many-to-Many queries faster?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq

A page in my application serves to display company 'problems' that have arisen in the past. These problems are submitted to the database by a single User, but one or many other users are assigned to deal with the problem, and vice-versa, a single user can be assigned to deal with one or many problems.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXWV7.png) is what the relationship looks like. 
My main trouble with this is that when issuing a `getAllProblems()` request, I have to go through all the users assigned to problems, which brings me to an ugly `foreach` within a `foreach`. My code looks like this:

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetProblems(String ClientUserHash) {
         this.ClientUserHash = ClientUserHash;

          HttpResponseMessage loResponse;

          if (!CheckClientHash()) {
              SetResponseToBad(out loResponse);
          } else {
              List<Int64> loFilteredObjects = PermissionsHelper.UserObjects(ClientUserID);
              var loModel = (from p in MeridianDatabase.Problems                                 
                             join o in MeridianDatabase.Objects on p.ObjectID equals o.ObjectID
                             where loFilteredObjects.Contains(o.ObjectID) && ((p.Archive == false) || (p.Archive == null))
                             select new ProblemsModel {
                                 ProblemID =     p.ProblemID,
                                 Description =   p.Description,
                                 Comment =       p.Comment,
                                 Status =        p.Status,
                                 Picture =       p.Picture,
                                 DateOpen =      p.DateOpen,
                                 DateClosed =    p.DateClosed,
                                 CategoryID =    p.CategoryID,
                                 CategoryName =  p.ProblemCategory.Name,
                                 ObjectID =      p.ObjectID,
                                 ObjectName =    p.Object.Name,
                                 EmployeeID =    p.EmployeeID,
                                 FullName =      p.Employee.Candidate.FirstName + " " + p.Employee.Candidate.LastName,
                                 CompanyName =   p.Object.Company.Name
                             }).ToList();
              foreach (ProblemsModel toProblem in loModel) {
                  var toDbUsers = MeridianDatabase.Problems.Where(x => x.ProblemID == toProblem.ProblemID).FirstOrDefault().Users;
                  if (toDbUsers.Count > 0) {
                      toProblem.ProblemUsers = new List<string>();
                      List<UsersModel> toUsersList = new List<UsersModel>();
                      foreach (User toUser in toDbUsers) {
                          toProblem.ProblemUsers.Add(String.Format("{0}-{1}", toUser.UserID, toUser.Username));
                          UsersModel toUserModel = new UsersModel() {
                              UserID = toUser.UserID,
                              Username = toUser.Username,
                              Password = toUser.Password,
                              Email = toUser.Email,
                              UserGroupsID = toUser.PermissionLevelID,
                              IsAdmin = toUser.IsAdmin,
                              LanguageID = toUser.LanguageID,
                              Name = toUser.Nickname
                          };
                          toUsersList.Add(toUserModel);
                      }
                      toProblem.Users = toUsersList;
                  }
              }
              loResponse = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, loModel);
          }
        return loResponse;
    }
```

I've tried using the in-code stopwatch and inferred that the `foreach` is the culprit. Can I get better performance without resorting to writing stored procedures? The way things are now, fetching 400 rows results in a 6-9 seconds wait, which is unacceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Change your loModel to join all three tables. Then, you will need one `foreach` only.

Comment: as I understand, this is not feasible using LINQ code. If you could provide a code snippet, that would mean something- otherwise, your answer is just stating the obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
from client_uo in UserObjects
join client_obj in Objects on client_uo.ObjectID == client_obj.ObjectID
join p in Problems on p.ObjectID == clt_obj.ObjectID
join pu in ProblemUsers on p.ProblemID == pu.ProblemID
join assignee in Users on pu.UserID == assignee.UserID
where client_obj.UserID == ClientUserID
```

that should produce a multi join that gets you from ClientUserID to Client-UserObjects to ProblemObjects to Problems to ProblemUsers (assignees?) to Users, with all the data available at one go. You may want to group it together, either by object, by problem, or by assigned user, depending on the display you're trying to produce.

Comment: The problem is that the Entity Framework doesn't see the ProblemUser (see pic above) as a separate table, but as a relation, so I can't access it the way I access users and problems.